# How can i test using multiple users , a sign up page with OTP using jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, one-time-password

My website has an OTP authentication at the time of registering to the website. I need to pass the otp that is send to both email id and mobile number into the next page, register and do rest steps in the website. I need to do it with 500 users. Please help me, if there is any solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter's [Mail Reader sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) (maybe in combination with [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)) to get the OTP from the email message generated by your system, store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) and use in login request.

See [How to Create a JMeter Script to Check Email During Registration AND Grab the Confirmation URL](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-create-jmeter-script-check-email-during-registration-and-grab-confirmation-url) article for detailed steps.

If you need do to it for 500 users I guess you'll need to have 500 email accounts, so you might need to use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read keep email/password pairs from .csv file.

Comment: Actually the Otp is passed as hidden field, and i could get the xpath also. but i dont know how to do with xpath extractor, its showing error